# find duplicates based on one column in a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have datatable like this

```
ColA     ColB      ColC
Friends  Columbus   US
Friends  London     UK
Business Paris      France
Personal Moscow     Russia
Friends  Sydney     Australasia
Personal Beijing    China
Relatives KL         Malaysia
```

I want get duplicate rows based on first column using LINQ.

Results should be like this

```
ColA     ColB      ColC
Friends  Columbus   US
Friends  London     UK
Personal Moscow     Russia
Friends  Sydney     Australasia
Personal Beijing    China
```

How to do this?

Comment: what exactly is your requirement? what logic are you looking for?

Comment: Use group by to group on ColA, then use the count to determine if you should or should not select it.

Comment: @James123 is looking for the rows which are ColA's value is duplicated

Comment: Sorry @andleer. I have modified question. Please see again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something similar to what you want to do:

```
from b in db.Tab
group b by b.Name into grp
where grp.Count() > 1
select grp.Key
```

Comment: it is datatable. I can not write b.Name in the query.

Comment: Similar is not enough

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select * from table1
where ColA IN (Select ColA from table1 group by colA 
having Count(ColA) > 1)
```

Check this **[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40862/3)**